# PySpark: Adding elements from python list into spark.sql() statement

Tags: python, sql, list, apache-spark, pyspark

have list in python that is used throughout my code:

```
pylist = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
```

I also have have a simple `spark.sql()` line that I need to execute:

```
query = spark.sql(
    """
    SELECT col1, col2, col3
    FROM database.table
    WHERE col3 IN ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D')
    """
)
```

I want to replace the list of elements in the `spark.sql()` statment with the python list so that that last line in the SQL is

```
...
AND col3 IN pylist
```

I am aware of using `{}` and `str.format` but I am struggling to understand if that's the correct option here, and how that workd.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, after some more research, I think I found the solution using `.format(tuple(pylist))`

The statement now is:

```
pylist = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']

s = """
    SELECT col1, col2, col3
    FROM database.table
    WHERE col3 IN {}
    """.format(tuple(pylist))

query = spark.sql(s)
```

Comment: This won't work if len(pylist)==1.

Answer (score 0):

Convert to tuple to get "()" instead of "[]" while converting to string

```
sql_str="SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM database.table WHERE col3 IN " + str(tuple(pylist))

query = spark.sql(sql_str)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use an f-string with `{tuple(pylist)}` as shown:

The statement now is:

```
pylist = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']

s = f"""
    SELECT col1, col2, col3
    FROM database.table
    WHERE col3 IN {tuple(pylist)}
    """

query = spark.sql(s)
```

Comment: This won't work if len(pylist)==1.